# Set page height to available space on mobiles

Tags: css

I am trying to make my web app take the full height of device.

I am using the 100vh on the body tag to do so, but Safari tab on iOS populates some height by itself so the user is having to scroll down to see the whole page. Is there any workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers come with a [default `margin` on the `body` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html). It's usually 8px.

```
body { margin: 8px; }
```

This will often launch a vertical scrollbar when the `body` element is set to 100% height. To remove the overflow, simply override the default with:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: This is not working. I will make a gif of my problem and post it later here.